# Ngrx - selector is not emitting new value after store change

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a state that looks something like this:

```
export interface State {
  modules: Module[];
}
```

And the Module interface is something like:

```
export interface Module {
  name: string;
  structure: {
    moduleID: string;
    icon: string;
    ...
  };
  data: [{id: string; value: string; }];
}
```

The data in the Modules is connected to input fields and combo boxes. When the user changes something in an input field, an action gets dispatched and the store gets updated by the reducer with the new data value for the given data object. I have already verified that the changes happen in the store.

The Reducer is doing the following: ( getModules() just returns the module with that name, and changeElementData() find the element to change and does data.value = value on it)

```
case fromTitelActions.SET_DATA: {
      const stateCopy = {...state};
      const moduleToChange = getModule(action.payload.nameOfModule, stateCopy.modules);
      action.payload.data.forEach(data => changeElementData(moduleToChange, data.Id, data.value));
      return stateCopy;
    }
```

I am trying to subscribe to specific data values and detect changes. My selector looks like this:

```
export const getDataElementValue = (moduleName, elementId) => createSelector(getModules,
     modules => {
        const module = modules.find(m => m.name === moduleName);
        const data = module.data.find( d => d.id === elementId);
        return data.value;
});
```

Upon subscribing to the selector I get the current value in it, but it never fires again, no matter how many times the reducer updates that particular data object. Any ideas what I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: That reducer is not a pure function - what does `retrieveState()` do? A reducer must be a pure function, which means that with a given input (i.e. set of parameters), it must always do the same thing. retrieveState takes no parameters so whatever it returns must be dependent on something other than the parameters passed to the reducer. I don't know if this is the problem or not, but it's /a/ problem :)

Comment: That was a mistake I made when editing the code to post here. Actually it just returns stateCopy. The state also gets saved in local storage but that doesn't really matter for my question so I skipped that. Thanks for pointing it out I edited my question.

Comment: You should not be saving the state into local storage in the reducer either, as that would also break the pure function aspect of it. If you want to keep the state in local storage, select the state and when the observable emits, put the state in local storage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is likely because your changeElementData function is not creating new objects when updating the property on moduleToChange.

I would guess you have something like this:

```
function changeElementData(moduleToChange, id, value) {
    moduleToChange.elements.forEach((el) => {
       if (el.id == id) el.value = value;
    });
}
```

You would need something like this:

```
case fromTitelActions.SET_DATA: {
    const stateCopy = {...state};
    stateCopy.modules = stateCopy.modules.map((moduleToChange) => {
        if (module.name != action.payload.nameOfModule) return moduleToChange;
        else return action.payload.data.map(data => changeElementData(moduleToChange, data.Id, data.value));
    });
    return stateCopy;
}

function changeElementData(moduleToChange, id, value) {
    let found: boolean = false;
    let newModule = module;
    if (moduleToChange.elements.find((el) => el.id == id)) {
        newModule = {
            ...moduleToChange,
            elements: moduleToChange.elements.map((el) => {
                if (el.id == id) return { ...el, value: value };
                else return el;
            })
        }
    }
    return newModule;
}
```

When updating a property of an object on the state, you must ALWAYS create a new containing object, because NGRX uses simple object equality to determine if something has changed and fire the relevant observables. If you update a property on an object, the object itself still has the same reference as its previous version, so NGRX will assume it is unchanged.